# Does webOS TV in LG supports HTML5 videos?

Tags: html, webos

Current source code:

```
<video controls loop>
<source src="video.webm" autoplay="autoplay" preload="auto" type='video/webm;codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
</video>
```

But it doesn't play with TV browser in LG.
Please help.

Comment: I recently tried the same in a LG TV and the video tag works, but I think it only supports `mp4` videos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer; I used a converter to support fallbacks in the browser.
See this: http://easyhtml5video.com/

Answer (score 0):

HTML 5.0 [*]  Partly supported,
Partly: satisfying 60-90% of the specifications.

For Video & Audio. Note that webm is ***not*** supported in emulator.

[image]

Reference
http://developer.lge.com/webOSTV/develop/web-app/webos-tv-platform/web-engine/
http://developer.lge.com/webOSTV/develop/web-app/webos-tv-platform/supported-media-formats/

Comment: The link to the supported media page appears to have moved here:  http://webostv.developer.lge.com/discover/webos-tv-platform/supported-media-formats/