# live streaming and .m3u8 video is working in firefox but video not showing in LG Webos emulator 3.0

Tags: http-live-streaming, webos, hls.js

i am using hlc to play streaming video in webos simulator. in firefox video is showing and working fine but in webos emulator 3.0 it is not showing anything. only getting current time and duration. what change does i  need for webos emulator 3.0.

> ```
>    .factory('playVideoFactory', function (SessionData) {
>         var i = 0;
>         return {
>         playVideoFunc: function (type, path, callBack, 
>          clearIntervalCallBackFunc) {
>                             if (Hls.isSupported()) {
>                 console.log("hls is supported");
>                 var video = document.getElementById(type);
>                 var hls = new Hls();
>                 hls.loadSource(path);
>                 hls.attachMedia(video);
>                                 console.log("hls");
>                 hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, function () {
>                     video.play();
>                 });
>                 var videoDurationInfo = setInterval(function () {
>                     callBack(video.duration, video.currentTime);
>                                 }, 1000);
>                 clearIntervalCallBackFunc(videoDurationInfo)
>             } else {
>                 console.log("hls is not supported");
>             }
>         }
>         }
>        })
> ```

video Tag in html

> ```
>   <video id="vod"> </video>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that the emulator does not support the same set of codecs that that TV itself does.  You may want to try transcoding.  I was able to find this link to supported formats on the LG webOS TV Developer site:

http://webostv.developer.lge.com/discover/webos-tv-platform/supported-media-formats/

(I got tipped to it from this SO:  [Does webOS TV in LG supports HTML5 videos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32990560/does-webos-tv-in-lg-supports-html5-videos/35380659#35380659) )