# HTML5 video webOS

Tags: html, html5-video, webos

I'm trying to play an external HTML5 video within a webOS web application. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32990560/does-webos-tv-in-lg-supports-html5-videos), webOS should support `.mp4` video, but whenever I try to play a HTML5 video within my application, the video simply won't load/play. My code (for testing purposes):

```
<video id="demo-video" autoplay muted loop>
                <source src="http://mirrors.standaloneinstaller.com/video-sample/jellyfish-25-mbps-hd-hevc.mp4"
                        type="video/mp4">
                Your Smart TV does not support the current video format (MP4)
</video>
```

I've tried different sources, but none of them seem to work. When testing in a browser, it does work, but when opening the application on a webOS Smart TV, nothing happens. Even trying to play a local `.mp4` file doesn't work.

I found out that `.play()` on the `video` element returns a Promise with status `pending`. Strange behaviour and reloading the source doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Did you test it on a real TV or just on the emulator?

Comment: @burakk real TV!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem: it had something to do with the styling I applied on the `<video>` element. When developing, Chrome showed the video just fine. But apparently, `border-radius` is not allowed? At least not in the version of Chrome used on the Smart TV and emulator. So if you're experiencing the same problem, check for styling that may cause the video not to play.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `width` and `height` attributes to your video tag. The video works on my TV.

```
<video id="demo-video" width="1920" height="1080" autoplay muted loop>
    <source src="http://mirrors.standaloneinstaller.com/video-sample/jellyfish-25-mbps-hd-hevc.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your Smart TV does not support the current video format (MP4)
</video>
```

Comment: Hmm. I found out that whenever I try to play a video, the promise returned by `.play()` returns status 'pending'. And it stays that way. Trying to find out why this happens. On the emulator, the same problem occurs.

Comment: Updated my post.

Comment: It might not be related, but I would remove the source tag within video tag and use src attribute of the video tag instead. 
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/play-returns-promise